# Stop RabbitMQ-Connection in Spring-Boot

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a spring-boot application that pulls all the messages from a RabbitMQ-queue and then terminates. I use `rabbitTemplate` from the package `spring-boot-starter-amqp` (version 2.4.0), namely `receiveAndConvert()`. Somehow, I cannot get my application to start and stop again. When the rabbitConnectionFactory is created, it will never stop.
According to Google and other stackoverflow-questions, calling `stop()` or `destroy()` on the rabbitTemplate should do the job, but that doesn't work.
The rabbitTemplate is injected in the constructor.

Here is some code:

```
rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
Object msg = getMessage();
while (msg != null) {
    try {
        String name = ((LinkedHashMap) msg).get(propertyName).toString();
        //business logic
        logger.debug("added_" + name);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("" + e.getMessage());
    }
    msg = getMessage();
}
rabbitTemplate.stop();
```

```
private Object getMessage() {
    try {
        return rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert(queueName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("" + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

So, how do you terminate the connection to RabbitMQ properly?

Thanks for your inquiry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `resetConnection()` on the `CachingConnectionFactory` to close the connection.

Or `close()` the application context.

Comment: It will simply reconnect after `resetConnection()`. Is there a way to prevent it from reconnecting? I have many many containers for multiple vhosts, and I need to disconnect only one of them, so shutting down application context is not an option for me.

Comment: I think I have managed to achieve what I wanted by first calling `shutdown()` on listener container, and then doing `resetConnection()`. Would be nice if you could confirm.

Comment: You should call `stop()` on the container (it will call shutdown).

Answer (score 0):

If I were to do it , I would use `@RabbitListener` to receive the messages and `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` to start and stop the listener. Sample Code is given below

```
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements ApplicationRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    public static final String queueName = "Hello";

    @Bean
    public Queue hello() {
        return new Queue(queueName);
    }

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate template;
    
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000, initialDelay = 500)
    public void send() {
        String message = "Hello World!";
        this.template.convertAndSend(queueName, message);
        System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
    }
    
    @Autowired
    RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        registry.getListenerContainer( Application.queueName).start();
        Thread.sleep(10000L);
        registry.getListenerContainer( Application.queueName).stop();
    }
}

@Component
class Receiver {
    @RabbitListener(id= Application.queueName,queues = Application.queueName)
    public void receive(String in) {
        System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + in + "'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Stopping the listener won't close the connection; call `resetConnection()` on the `CachingConnectionFactory`.